# How can I write down a significative statistic test?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, normality-assumption

I'm studying statistics and thinking about some exercise to do, I came up with the idea to write them down my own. However, I'm coming across some problems, for which I'm asking for help.

I have 35 subjects with these scores of a random test, divided between pre and post. I'm trying to fit them in a normal distribution, having a not so different variance between them, and a significative shapiro wilk test. I can't understand how to change them in order to get my results.... any help? Thanks in advance

```
pre test;post test 
45;52
45;52
45;52
45;52
45;52
45;52
44;50
44;50
44;50
44;50
44;50
46;53
46;53
46;53
46;53
46;53
43;49
43;49
43;49
43;49
47;54
47;54
47;54
47;54
42;48
42;48
42;48
48;55
48;55
48;55
41;47
41;47
49;56
49;56
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: The question is: how can i change the values to match my idea of a test? These values give me a not-normal distribution or an excessive variance

Comment: If this question is related to your study, it is encouraged to add the self-study tag and read its wiki https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to use tests you have learned in you statistics class for data from an outside project. Also it seems you're wondering whether to use a paired t test. I think that may not be a good choice, but not exactly for the reasons you give. I show some possibly appropriate alternative tests, You can google for more information on sign, Wilcoxon signed rank, and  permutation tests (if not in the text you used), or ask for help if you can't find information you need.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to transform the data (taking logs, square roots, etc.) if they do not seem suitable for the test you have in mind. But, perhaps more often, the best course of action is to find a test that works for the data in their original form. I explore this approach in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to know if there is a difference between pre-test and post-test values. Unless I have misread your data, for every one of the 35 subjects, the post-test score is higher. So you can use a simple sign test, based on a binomial distribution.

Under the null hypothesis that there is no difference between pre and post-test, the probability that the post-test score was always larger the the pre-test score is $(1/2)^{35} \approx 2.9 \times 10^{-11} < 0.01 = 1\%.$
So you can reject the null hypothesis in favor of the alternative that post-test scores are larger at the 1% level of significance. Computation in R:

```
.5^35
[1] 2.910383e-11
```

**Formal sign test.** For a slightly less-obvious case, consider 35 fictitious "post minus pre" differences as follows:

```
dif
 [1]  2  1  3  4  2  1  4  2  3  3  3  1  1 -1  4  2  1  1  2  1
[21]  2  2  1  3  3  2  2  0  1  0  0  2  1  2  3
```

In summary, there are 32 non-zero differences, of which 31
are positive.

```
table(dif)
dif
-1  0  1  2  3  4 
 1  3 10 11  7  3
```

Thus, the P-value for a one-sided sign test would be nearly $0,$ computed in R as follows. Again, the null hypothesis is rejected.

```
pbinom(1, 31, .5)
[1] 1.490116e-08
```

**Wilcoxon signed rank test.** If you have no tied or zero differences, you may want to try a nonparametric one-sided Wilcoxon signed-rank test.
For my fictitious data I get a warning message that the
P-value may not be accurate:

```
wilcox.test(dif, alt="g", cor=F)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  dif
V = 522, p-value = 5.361e-07
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location is greater than 0

Warning messages:
1: In wilcox.test.default(dif, alt = "g", cor = F) :
   cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In wilcox.test.default(dif, alt = "g", cor = F) :
   cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
```

Below we show that a permutation test can find an accurate P-value, even when ties and 0's are present. You say that the your data are not normal; according to the Shapiro-Wilk test, neither are my fictitious data `dif`. So one may wonder if the test
*statistic* of a t test has Student's t *distribution,* and so doubt the resulting P-value. [Notice that It is the *differences* that would need to be normal, not necessarily the pre or post scores.]

```
shapiro.test(dif)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  dif
W = 0.93772, p-value = 0.04772
```

However, the t *statistic* seems a reasonable way to
express how far from the mean of the differences is from $0.$ Thus, we use the t statistic as a 'metric' in a permutation test. If pre and post scores are the same
we are just as likely to get positive and negative differences. [Some elementary texts seem to say it is OK to do a t test anytime the sample size exceeds 30, but this is not good advice.]

**Permutation test.** We can get a good idea of the distribution of the t statistic under the null hypothesis by repeatedly and
randomly switching the signs of the differences. If
t statistics for differences with switched signs tend to
be smaller than the t statitistic for `dif`, that is a good indication that $H_0$ is not true.

The permutation distribution of the t statistic under $h_0$ is approximated by the R simulation below.

```
t.obs = t.test(dif, alt="g")$stat; t.obs
       t 
9.013927 
t.prm = replicate(10^5, t.test( 
  dif*sample(c(-1,1),35,rep=T), alo="g" )$stat )
mean(t.prm > t.obs)
[1] 0
```

So the P-value is essentially $0$ and $H_0$ is rejected.
The figure below shows the simulated permutation distribution of the t statistic.

[image]

```
hdr = "Simulated Permutation Dist'n of t Statistics"
hist(t.prm, prob=T, xlim=c(-10,10), col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
abline(v = t.obs, lwd=2, lty="dotted", col="red")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me... I feel I've understood better these concept now!